# Communicating with HSM python

Tags: python, smartcard, pkcs#11, hsm

I'm attempting to establish a connection with a remote machine through this script. The script is being run on the remote machine attempting to open a session, which I believe I'm doing incorrectly. I'm trying to access slot zero in the library `opt/PTK/lib/libcryptoki.so` which contains a keystore via smart card (i.e. `00000010300000A2`) However the Available slots is returning zero.

**CORRECT SCRIPT**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PyKCS11.LowLevel import *

a = CPKCS11Lib()
info = CK_INFO()
slotInfo = CK_SLOT_INFO()
lib='/opt/PTK/lib/libcryptoki.so'
slotList = ckintlist()

print("Load of " + lib + ": " + str(a.Load(lib, 1)))
a.C_Initialize()
print("C_GetInfo:", hex(a.C_GetInfo(info)))
print("Library manufacturerID:", info.GetManufacturerID())

del info

print("C_GetSlotList(NULL): " + hex(a.C_GetSlotList(0, slotList)))
print("\tAvailable Slots: " + str(len(slotList)))
```

**OUTPUT**

`ctstat
ProtectToolkit C Status Utility 4.3.0
Copyright (c) Safenet, Inc. 2009-2013
ShowAllSlots:4 slots, 4 with tokens
Slot ID 0
    Description      : ProtectServer K5E:00045
    Manufacturer     : SafeNet Inc.
    Hardware Version : 65.00
    Firmware Version : 3.20
Token for Slot ID 0
    Label            : CKM
    Manufacturer     : SafeNet Inc.
    Model            : K5E:PL25
    Serial Number    : 502152:00045
    Hardware Version : 65.00
    Firmware Version : 3.20`

Comment: Does `pkcs11.getInfo()` say anything interesting?

Comment: It returns the following traceback:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Cryptoki.py", line 18, in <module>
    info = pkcs11.getInfo()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyKCS11/__init__.py", line 475, in getInfo
    raise PyKCS11Error(rv)
PyKCS11.PyKCS11Error: CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID (0x00000003) ` @viraptor

Comment: Does this script detect any slots when run directly on the remote machine? Do commands like `ctstat`/`hsmstate` work when run directly on the remote machine (i.e. is your HSM installed correctly)? Do they work remotely? Note: this comment assumes SafeNet/Gemalto ProtectProcessing product.

Comment: Yes they work remotely. 4 slots with 4 tokens. I'm trying to access slot 0 that contains the tokens i desire for testing. What would that look like? @vlp
```print("C_GetSlotList(NULL): " + hex(a.C_GetSlotList(0, slotList)))
print("\tAvailable Slots: " + str(len(slotList)))``` this prints "Available slots: 4" @vlp

Comment: Does this mean that your script works remotely when using the LowLevel API and fails when using the "object API"? (And please note that you pasted the output of ctstat instead of the actual `Available slots: 4` into your question)

Comment: The script runs using the LowLevel API Calls like `C_GetInfo` .. so I can print session information, token info, slot info, etc.. Can't seem to find correct pkcs11 interface to make a call to pull an object from the smart card. @vlp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly for me. In terms of the connection.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(("ssh", "remoteuser@host", "echo", "1"), 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```